# ERROR ITMS-9000 "Invalid Image Path" when submitting with xcode 6

Tags: xcode, xcasset

When validating or submitting my app with xcode 6, I get the error:

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced
under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon120x120'"
```

I've checked my plist file, and there is no entry for CFBundleIcons. I am using an asset catalog, which I can see is configured correctly under the General target settings (it also builds properly with the icons on a device). I've tried removing and re-adding the catalogues, as well. My best guess is that there is some kind of bug in xcode when using multiple asset catalogs across multiple targets. Any ideas?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This will make your head explode. Since xcode now offers @3x and carplay icons in the asset catalog, I filled everything out with the appropriate sized icons. Turns out my problem was solved by REMOVING the carplay icon and just leaving its spot blank.

Comment: same happened, amazing.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I tried for more than 10 hours to realize that what I was doing wrong. !!!!

Comment: Removing that icon won't affect carplay support, will it?

Comment: I can't help but to laugh. Thank you for figuring it out!

Comment: Didn't help for me, I'm afraid. Same problem.

(no CFBundleIcons lines in my .plist, two configurations)

Comment: I saw that the CarPlay icon was a 120x120, but figured, nah, that'd be stupid if that was it...

Comment: Thanks so much! Apple could make this a little easier, huh?

Comment: Where is the CarPlay Icon? I can not find it.  Ok, never mind, I found it.  So stupid for Apple is doing that!!!

Comment: The string "CFBundleIcons" appeared nowhere in my entire project.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when switching my project to use the asset catalog, except mine was with a different image size:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid image path - No image found at the path referenced under 'CFBundleIcons':'AppIcon60x60'"

I fixed it by manually adding the image to

```
Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json
```

Like so:

```
{
  "size" : "60x60",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "filename" : "Icon-60.png",
  "scale" : "1x"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Image-xcassets where you app icon is ->  Click you Appicon folder -> On the rightmost options there is Attribute inspector ( Inverted triangle) . Click that . Uncheck Carplay.