# ERROR ITMS-9000 AppIcon29x29 AppIcon40x40 Xcode 6

Tags: submit, ios8, app-store-connect, xcode6, imageicon

I'm getting crazy... I've a problem to submit the app in ItunesConnect with XCODE 6 beta version because I get two errors like this:

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon29x29'"
```

and

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon40x40'"
```

I've passed all this badly day to find a solution but anything found....
Someone have my similar problem like this: [Appicon120x120](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907195/error-itms-9000-invalid-image-path-when-submitting-with-xcode-6) but the solution is no good for me...
In fact I've not Icon for the car:
I tried a lot of solution like:

- replace all icons
- create new assets
- replace all name of the icon like: AppIcon29x29.png and AppIcon29x29@2x.png
- create new icons
- repetutly upload and browser on the web ......

Really i'm getting crazy. Thank you advance to help me please.

Comment: Anybody have my same issue? o_O

Comment: Ok I solved it in this way:

- Insert only the icon called: Iphone App IOS 7,8 60pt

deleted all icon called:
- iPhone Spotlight -IOS 5,6 Settings - IOS 5-8 29pt
- IPhone Spotlight IOS 7,8 40pt

I'm getting better 

Problem Solved! ;)